# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n^{-n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the following converge or diverge?
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n^{-n},
$$
where$$
a_n = \int_1^n \sin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)} \,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
My friends thought this sum would converge. I think we should do the square root test, checking the value of $t=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{a_n}$. And we knew that this goes to $0$. So, that would make the sum to converge…

Is there any problem in my ideas? Some said that this sum diverges, which I can never understand why…

It will be great if someone can explain me on this… Better with some proofs I can understand. (We are students learning calculus.)

Comment: You should find out what happens to $a_n$ as $n$ gets large.  Is it increasing in $n$?  Does it ever get larger than 2?

Comment: What I found out is that a_n goes to infinity when n gets large...

Comment: So you know $a_n \geq 2$ for all sufficiently large $n$.  Can you infer anything from that, like a comparison?

Comment: Yes I thought that it would converge that way. Isn't it?

Comment: I do not follow your above comment.  Can you make an argument that uses the fact $a_n\geq 2$ for all sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: Also, is there any reason I can't use the root test in this case?

Comment: Then, please demonstrate how to use the root test.

Comment: I think it would diverge if you sum up just the inverse of all these integrals.

Comment: Using that, we know that without finite number of cases a_n^(-n) is smaller than 2^(-n) so we can use the comparison test to prove that the original sum converges...

Comment: Yes, I would call that the "comparison" test rather than the "root test."

Comment: Using the root test, we must find out the root limit (1/a_n). If this is smaller than 1, the sum would converge. So what I did is computing lim n to inf (1/a_n), and it goes to 0....

Comment: MrMatzeroni >> can you tell me why..?

Comment: Michael>> Yes I think you're right. That was our test question I solved like several hours ago. I'd like to know if I'm right or not, cause I answered it with root test.

Comment: Well, you already answered it another way with the comparison test.  I do not know what the "root test" is.  What is a "root limit"?

Comment: If we look at sin(x) around 0, Taylor expansion gives us sin(y)=y+o(y^2). Your function in the integral behaves for x to infinity basically like sin(1/sqrt(x))=1/sqrt(x) +o(1/x). Thus if you increase your upper bound n to infinity and integrate, you get a_n≈ 2sqrt(n)+c(n), where c is some function which can be neglected. By comparison you get a series that behaves like sum over (1/sqrt(n)) which diverges. Or in the case of the reciprocals with exponent n: 1/sqrt(n)^n, then it converges by comparison test.

Comment: I do not think there is such a thing as the "square root test" as you mention.  There is a "root test" here that seems consistent with your work if you apply it to $b_n = a_n^{-n}$, and evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |b_n|^{1/n}$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test

Comment: Ah yeah I misused the word...I learned math Korean so I didn't know the correct word....thanks

Comment: So the given series converges...right?

Comment: @GSS : Yes it converges.  In fact, you had already proved convergence in your response to my $a_n\geq 2$ comment, where you said above "Using that, we know that without finite number of cases a_n^(-n) is smaller than 2^(-n) so we can use the comparison teset to prove that the original sum converges..." (I think you meant "we know that for all but a finite number of cases we have $a_n^{-n} \leq 2^{-n}$).  Your root test is also good to show convergence (I did not know the exact test $b_n^{1/n}$ you were performing, I would have understood more clearly if you gave more details on that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct: $a_n$ is positive and by applying the root test the convergence of the series $\sum_n (1/a_n)^{n}$ follows as soon as you show that $1/a_n\to L<1$. Here we have that $1/a_n\to 0$ so $\sum_n (1/a_n)^{n}$ converges.

In fact, $\sin(t)\geq 2t/\pi$ for $t\in [0,\pi/2]$ ($\sin(x)$ is concave in that interval). Hence for $n>1$,
$$a_n = \int_1^n \sin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)} \,dx\geq \frac{2}{\pi}\int_1^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx =\frac{4(\sqrt{n}-1)}{\pi}\implies 0<\frac{1}{a_n}\leq \frac{\pi}{4(\sqrt{n}-1)}$$
which implies that $1/a_n\to 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

P.S. By the way $\sin(t)\leq  t$ for $t\geq 0$ implies that
$$a_n = \int_1^n \sin{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)} \,dx\leq \int_1^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx ={2(\sqrt{n}-1)}\implies \frac{1}{a_n}\geq \frac{1}{2(\sqrt{n}-1)}$$
which implies that $\sum_n (1/a_n)=+\infty$.

Comment: So, 1/a_n is smaller than that. I understood it... But I don't get how we get the solution by that. Pi/(4(sqrtn-1) is still diverging...

Comment: Thanks. I understood what you meant

Comment: Are you sure that the given series is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n^{-n}$? Note that the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n^{-1}$ is divergent.

Comment: Yeah given series was sigma (a_n)^(-n)

Comment: @GSS Ok. Anyway I left a comment in my P.S.

Answer (score 1):

From $\sin x<x$, and for $n>4$,

$$\left(\int_1^n\sin\frac1{\sqrt x}dx\right)^{-n}<\left(2\sqrt n\right)^{-n}<\frac1{n^2}$$

and the series converges.

Comment: +1 And compliments for your way to reach the $10^5$! Awesome!

Comment: @VonNeumann: I have rewritten in a more concise way (you can withdraw your vote if you think it got worse :-). Thanks for the comment !

Comment: On the contrary, I like the "new" approach very much!

Answer (score 0):

As $n\to +\infty$ you have that asymptotically

$$\int_1^n\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \sim 2\sqrt{n}$$

Thence the related series goes like $\frac{1}{n^{n+1/2}}$ which converges.

Comment: Be aware that he takes the power with -n. It would diverge if he sums up alle the inverses though.

Comment: Can't understand the downvote nor the above comment. Was the question changed ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust No the question wasn't changed, and I don't understand the down vote (and the previous comment) either... I think it's become a fashion sometimes (the down-voting)

Comment: @VonNeumann : I am flagging this answer for moderator, only because it seems there may be a Stackexchange bug (not because you or anyone did anything wrong, and certainly there is no reason to remove your answer).  I will explain my concern in my next comment, perhaps you or a moderator could illuminate.

Comment: Von Neumann or moderator: Perhaps stackexchange bug since this answer has no edit trail such as "edited 7 hours ago." As I recall, this answer was originally given with an opposite conclusion. I believe the downvote and the MrMatzetoni comment were given then. Next, Von Neumann wrote a message "I am deleting because I misread the question." Then Von Neumann deleted. This morning I observe the answer re-appears, with downvote and comment retained, but no edit trail shown. Stackexchange presents this as if the answer was given originally in its current form, which is not the case.

Comment: @Michael If the edit became within  the five minute grace window, then no marker is left in the edit history. Some answerers are abusing this to get an earlier timestamp to their answer, and add significant amounts of material during the grace period, pretending it was there from the beginning. I have no reason to suspect that anything similar took place here. A comment will "kill this grace window", so if you see an attempt to abuse the system like this, you can leave a comment. Any edit coming after a comment will be logged normally.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : I agree nobody was trying to abuse the system here.   But I am confused because the answer was deleted and still no edit trail. Perhaps the "grace window" also includes a delete/undelete and was not killed by downvotes/comments in this case, or perhaps those were given "simultaneously" while an edit took place and the system had to make a decision about which came first.  Thanks for your response.  I did not know about grace windows. The grace window idea is actually nice since anyone can make initial typos/mistakes.

Comment: @Michael I know nothing about the "hidden system" of down votes / review / watching the log of the evolution of an answer (edits, deletion, un-deletion...). In my "defense", yes I misread the question because I read $a_n^n$, without the minus sign. This is why I answered in the opposite way. 
Then I immediately deleted the answer because I noticed my error, but most of all: because i wanted to edit it in a good correct answer, and many times when you do it under the sun, down votes arrive the same. Whilst if you first delete it and then edit, and then undelete, no down votes appear.

Comment: @Michael you can naviagte to the revision site manually https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2704545/revisions You will not see an edit either but you can see the del/undel mentioned above. Since the timestamps show that the del/undel happened within five minutes no separate version was locked. Maybe a delete should trigger an extra revision but this is orthogonal.